# How to add track numbers to the filename with youtube-dl?

Tags: youtube-dl

I want to name downloaded audio files in playlists and albums by the track order. Only the `track_number` [output path](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#output-template) command seems to be directly related and results in every file being prefixed with `NA` string.

[image: screenshot]

Affects both Soundcloud and Bandcamp (low-bitrate audio stream is always provided for free).

---

sample command:

```
youtube-dl -f bestaudio -o "%(playlist_title)s/%(track_number)s.%(title)s.%(ext)s" url
```

Comment: I can only find this bug report: https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/13326

Comment: where is playlist_title and track_number in the file name? why %(playlist_title)s/% instead %(playlist_title)s%

Comment: Just a guess: Not Applicable?  Perhaps there is no track number for the file.

Comment: @SlickNutz: `playlist_title` is the title of the subfolder, I should perhaps remove it from the sample command for clarity.

Comment: use `youtube-dl -f bestaudio -o "%(playlist_title)s%(track_number)s.%(title)s.%(ext)s" url` and does that work

Comment: @BillHileman: I've assumed that youtube-dl is able to name based on its sequential download order.

Comment: what is your desired output of the mp3 files?

Comment: @SlickNutz: [track number].[title].[filename extension]

Comment: @SlickNutz: As far as I can see `NA.` is now added after the playlist title to the filename.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[youtube-dl has been updated with Bandcamp support](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/pull/17366) for the `track_number` command. [Soundcloud doesn't provide the track number for youtube-dl](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/issues/17266#issuecomment-416645899), but you can use the playlist [template](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl#output-template) ([source](https://www.reddit.com/r/DataHoarder/comments/98j282/how_do_you_archive_soundcloud_albums/)):

```
-o "%(playlist)s\%(playlist_index)s - %(title)s.%(ext)s"
```

Comment: use 02d formatting in -o "%(track_number)02d. %(title)s.%(ext)s" for numbers 01. 02 etc.